# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in this program at the if statement i==7 when all the other before if statements are executing just fine?

Tags: c++

*I'm also a beginner in c++ so I am sorry if there are any mistakes.
The first two messages after the if statement i==7 prints but after that segmentation fault occurs. All the other before statements prints just fine. Any help would be really appreciated.*

```
for (x = 0; x < m; x++) {
if (s[x].getrollno() == rno) {
    b = s[x].getsem();
    if (c[x].flag == 1) {
        s[x].output1();
        cout << "******";
        c[x].output();
        cout << "******";
    }
    if (p[x].flag == 1) {
        cout << "*****";
        s[x].output1();
        p[x].output();
        cout << "*****";
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= b; i++) {
        if (i == 3) {
            cout << "****";
            s[x].output1();
            s3[x].output();
            cout << "****";
        } else if (i == 4) {
            cout << "****";
            s[x].output1();
            s4[x].output();
            cout << "****";
        } else if (i == 5) {
            cout << "*****";
            s[x].output1();

            s5[x].output();
            cout << "*****";
        } else if (i == 6) {
            cout << "*****";
            s[x].output1();
            s6[x].output();
            cout << "*****";
        } else if (i == 7) {
            cout << "GOING!";
            cout << "****";
            cout << "GOING";
            s[x].output1();
            s7[x].output();
            cout << "******";
        } else {
            cout << "******";
            s[x].output1();
            cout << "CALLING";
            s8[x].output();
            cout << "******";
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: There's too much irrelevant code, and not enough relevant code to figure out what might be wrong. If you can reduce your program to a [simple, complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem, then maybe someone could figure it out.

Comment: Time to break out your debugger!

Comment: Without knowing what s[n].output() does, knowing what s is, how long the array is, etc it's very hard to tell. Just not enough info to use.

Comment: **Which debugger do I use?@lightningracisinorbit**

Answer (score 1):

Likely `x` is out of bounds of the `s7` array/vector, or `s7[x]` is not correctly initialized.

Comment: _@sth, No, i checked x isn't out of bounds and s7[x] is correctly initialized._